Graylog packetbeat on ubuntu
I have a problem with elastic packetbeat on ubuntu
I use graylog version 3.1 and elasticsearch 6.8 and mongo 4
installed packetbeat 7 but nothing received on graylog input
`bahram@localdomain:~$ sudo curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200'
[sudo] password for bahram:
{
"name" : "myPLie2",
"cluster_name" : "graylog",
"cluster_uuid" : "7TUMoNZpTk6DUY4ssc3y1A",
"version" : {
"number" : "6.8.23",
"build_flavor" : "oss",
"build_type" : "deb",
"build_hash" : "4f67856",
"build_date" : "2022-01-06T21:30:50.087716Z",
"build_snapshot" : false,
"lucene_version" : "7.7.3",
"minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
"minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
},
"tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
bahram@localdomain:~$ sudo mongod --version
db version v4.0.28

curl -L -O https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/beats/packetbeat/packetbeat-oss-7.15.1-amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i packetbeat-oss-7.15.1-amd64.deb

bahram@ubuntu192:~$ sudo packetbeat test config
bahram@ubuntu192:~$ sudo packetbeat test config
Config OK
bahram@ubuntu192:~$ sudo packetbeat test output
logstash: 192.168.110.131:5050...
connection...
parse host... OK
dns lookup... OK
addresses: 192.168.110.131
dial up... OK
TLS... WARN secure connection disabled
talk to server... OK
bahram@ubuntu192:~$ sudo systemctl status packetbeat.service
● packetbeat.service - Packetbeat analyzes network traffic and sends the data to Elasticsearch.
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/packetbeat.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-03-02 02:40:40 PST; 250ms ago
Docs: https://www.elastic.co/beats/packetbeat
Main PID: 61101 (packetbeat)
Tasks: 8 (limit: 7075)
Memory: 38.1M
CGroup: /system.slice/packetbeat.service
└─61101 /usr/share/packetbeat/bin/packetbeat --environment systemd -c /etc/packetbeat/packetbeat.yml --path.home /usr/share/packetbeat --path.config /etc/packetbeat --pa>
Mar 02 02:40:40 ubuntu192.168.110.130 systemd[1]: Stopped Packetbeat analyzes network traffic and sends the data to Elasticsearch..
Mar 02 02:40:40 ubuntu192.168.110.130 systemd[1]: Started Packetbeat analyzes network traffic and sends the data to Elasticsearch..
Mar 02 02:40:41 ubuntu192.168.110.130 packetbeat[61101]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2022-03-02T02:40:41.035-0800","log.origin":{"file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":679}>
Mar 02 02:40:41 ubuntu192.168.110.130 packetbeat[61101]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2022-03-02T02:40:41.035-0800","log.origin":{"file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":687}>
Mar 02 02:40:43 ubuntu192.168.110.130 packetbeat[61101]: {"log.level":"warn","@timestamp":"2022-03-02T02:40:43.811-0800","log.logger":"add_cloud_metadata","log.origin":{"file.name":">
Mar 02 02:40:43 ubuntu192.168.110.130 packetbeat[61101]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2022-03-02T02:40:43.984-0800","log.logger":"seccomp","log.origin":{"file.name":"seccomp/sec>
Mar 02 02:40:44 ubuntu192.168.110.130 packetbeat[61101]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2022-03-02T02:40:43.985-0800","log.logger":"beat","log.origin":{"file.name":"instance/beat.>
Mar 02 02:40:44 ubuntu192.168.110.130 packetbeat[61101]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2022-03-02T02:40:43.985-0800","log.logger":"beat","log.origin":{"file.name":"instance/beat.>
Mar 02 02:40:44 ubuntu192.168.110.130 packetbeat[61101]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2022-03-02T02:40:43.985-0800","log.logger":"beat","log.origin":{"file.name":"instance/beat.>
Mar 02 02:40:43 ubuntu192.168.110.130 systemd[1]: packetbeat.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 02 02:40:44 ubuntu192.168.110.130 packetbeat[61101]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2022-03-02T02:40:43.986-0800","log.logger":"beat","log.origin":{"file.name":"instance/beat.>
Mar 02 02:40:43 ubuntu192.168.110.130 systemd[1]: packetbeat.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 02 02:40:44 ubuntu192.168.110.130 packetbeat[61101]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2022-03-02T02:40:43.986-0800","log.logger":"beat","log.origin":{"file.name":"instance/beat.>
Mar 02 02:40:44 ubuntu192.168.110.130 packetbeat[61101]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2022-03-02T02:40:43.986-0800","log.origin":{"file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":332}>
Mar 02 02:40:44 ubuntu192.168.110.130 packetbeat[61101]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2022-03-02T02:40:43.987-0800","log.logger":"publisher","log.origin":{"file.name":"pipeline/>
Mar 02 02:40:44 ubuntu192.168.110.130 packetbeat[61101]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2022-03-02T02:40:43.988-0800","log.origin":{"file.name":"procs/procs.go","file.line":103},">
Mar 02 02:40:44 ubuntu192.168.110.130 packetbeat[61101]: {"log.level":"warn","@timestamp":"2022-03-02T02:40:43.989-0800","log.logger":"cfgwarn","log.origin":{"file.name":"sip/plugin.>
Mar 02 02:40:44 ubuntu192.168.110.130 packetbeat[61101]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2022-03-02T02:40:43.989-0800","log.logger":"monitoring","log.origin":{"file.name":"log/log.>
Mar 02 02:40:44 ubuntu192.168.110.130 packetbeat[61101]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2022-03-02T02:40:43.989-0800","log.logger":"kibana","log.origin":{"file.name":"kibana/clien>
Mar 02 02:40:44 ubuntu192.168.110.130 packetbeat[61101]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2022-03-02T02:40:43.992-0800","log.logger":"monitoring","log.origin":{"file.name":"log/log.>
Mar 02 02:40:44 ubuntu192.168.110.130 packetbeat[61101]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2022-03-02T02:40:43.992-0800","log.logger":"monitoring","log.origin":{"file.name":"log/log.>
Mar 02 02:40:44 ubuntu192.168.110.130 packetbeat[61101]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2022-03-02T02:40:43.992-0800","log.logger":"monitoring","log.origin":{"file.name":"log/log.>
Mar 02 02:40:44 ubuntu192.168.110.130 packetbeat[61101]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2022-03-02T02:40:43.992-0800","log.origin":{"file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":495}>
Mar 02 02:40:44 ubuntu192.168.110.130 packetbeat[61101]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2022-03-02T02:40:43.992-0800","log.origin":{"file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":102>
Mar 02 02:40:44 ubuntu192.168.110.130 packetbeat[61101]: Exiting: error connecting to Kibana: fail to get the Kibana version: HTTP GET request to http://localhost:5601/api/status fai>
Mar 02 02:40:44 ubuntu192.168.110.130 systemd[1]: packetbeat.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 681.
lines 1-36/36 (END)...skipping...
● packetbeat.service - Packetbeat analyzes network traffic and sends the data to Elasticsearch.
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/packetbeat.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-03-02 02:40:40 PST; 250ms ago
Docs: https://www.elastic.co/beats/packetbeat
Main PID: 61101 (packetbeat)
Tasks: 8 (limit: 7075)
Memory: 38.1M
CGroup: /system.slice/packetbeat.service
└─61101 /usr/share/packetbeat/bin/packetbeat --environment systemd -c /etc/packetbeat/packetbeat.yml --path.home /usr/share/packetbeat --path.config /etc/packetbeat --path.data /var/lib/packetbeat --path.l>
Mar 02 02:40:40 ubuntu192.168.110.130 systemd[1]: Stopped Packetbeat analyzes network traffic and sends the data to Elasticsearch..
Mar 02 02:40:40 ubuntu192.168.110.130 systemd[1]: Started Packetbeat analyzes network traffic and sends the data to Elasticsearch..
Mar 02 02:40:41 ubuntu192.168.110.130 packetbeat[61101]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2022-03-02T02:40:41.035-0800","log.origin":{"file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":679},"message":"Home path: [/usr/share/p>
Mar 02 02:40:41 ubuntu192.168.110.130 packetbeat[61101]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2022-03-02T02:40:41.035-0800","log.origin":{"file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":687},"message":"Beat ID: 1cda43ff-bccb-4>
Mar 02 02:40:43 ubuntu192.168.110.130 packetbeat[61101]: {"log.level":"warn","@timestamp":"2022-03-02T02:40:43.811-0800","log.logger":"add_cloud_metadata","log.origin":{"file.name":"add_cloud_metadata/provider_aws_ec2.>
Mar 02 02:40:43 ubuntu192.168.110.130 packetbeat[61101]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2022-03-02T02:40:43.984-0800","log.logger":"seccomp","log.origin":{"file.name":"seccomp/seccomp.go","file.line":124},"message":>
Mar 02 02:40:44 ubuntu192.168.110.130 packetbeat[61101]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2022-03-02T02:40:43.985-0800","log.logger":"beat","log.origin":{"file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":1050},"message":"Bea>
Mar 02 02:40:44 ubuntu192.168.110.130 packetbeat[61101]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2022-03-02T02:40:43.985-0800","log.logger":"beat","log.origin":{"file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":1059},"message":"Bui>
Mar 02 02:40:44 ubuntu192.168.110.130 packetbeat[61101]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2022-03-02T02:40:43.985-0800","log.logger":"beat","log.origin":{"file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":1062},"message":"Go >
Mar 02 02:40:43 ubuntu192.168.110.130 systemd[1]: packetbeat.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 02 02:40:44 ubuntu192.168.110.130 packetbeat[61101]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2022-03-02T02:40:43.986-0800","log.logger":"beat","log.origin":{"file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":1066},"message":"Hos>
Mar 02 02:40:43 ubuntu192.168.110.130 systemd[1]: packetbeat.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 02 02:40:44 ubuntu192.168.110.130 packetbeat[61101]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2022-03-02T02:40:43.986-0800","log.logger":"beat","log.origin":{"file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":1095},"message":"Pro>
Mar 02 02:40:44 ubuntu192.168.110.130 packetbeat[61101]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2022-03-02T02:40:43.986-0800","log.origin":{"file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":332},"message":"Setup Beat: packetbeat; >
Mar 02 02:40:44 ubuntu192.168.110.130 packetbeat[61101]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2022-03-02T02:40:43.987-0800","log.logger":"publisher","log.origin":{"file.name":"pipeline/module.go","file.line":113},"message>
Mar 02 02:40:44 ubuntu192.168.110.130 packetbeat[61101]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2022-03-02T02:40:43.988-0800","log.origin":{"file.name":"procs/procs.go","file.line":103},"message":"Process watcher disabled",>
Mar 02 02:40:44 ubuntu192.168.110.130 packetbeat[61101]: {"log.level":"warn","@timestamp":"2022-03-02T02:40:43.989-0800","log.logger":"cfgwarn","log.origin":{"file.name":"sip/plugin.go","file.line":67},"message":"BETA:>
Mar 02 02:40:44 ubuntu192.168.110.130 packetbeat[61101]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2022-03-02T02:40:43.989-0800","log.logger":"monitoring","log.origin":{"file.name":"log/log.go","file.line":142},"message":"Star>
Mar 02 02:40:44 ubuntu192.168.110.130 packetbeat[61101]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2022-03-02T02:40:43.989-0800","log.logger":"kibana","log.origin":{"file.name":"kibana/client.go","file.line":182},"message":"Ki>
Mar 02 02:40:44 ubuntu192.168.110.130 packetbeat[61101]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2022-03-02T02:40:43.992-0800","log.logger":"monitoring","log.origin":{"file.name":"log/log.go","file.line":192},"message":"Tota>
Mar 02 02:40:44 ubuntu192.168.110.130 packetbeat[61101]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2022-03-02T02:40:43.992-0800","log.logger":"monitoring","log.origin":{"file.name":"log/log.go","file.line":193},"message":"Upti>
Mar 02 02:40:44 ubuntu192.168.110.130 packetbeat[61101]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2022-03-02T02:40:43.992-0800","log.logger":"monitoring","log.origin":{"file.name":"log/log.go","file.line":160},"message":"Stop>
Mar 02 02:40:44 ubuntu192.168.110.130 packetbeat[61101]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2022-03-02T02:40:43.992-0800","log.origin":{"file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":495},"message":"packetbeat stopped.","se>
Mar 02 02:40:44 ubuntu192.168.110.130 packetbeat[61101]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2022-03-02T02:40:43.992-0800","log.origin":{"file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":1025},"message":"Exiting: error connect>
Mar 02 02:40:44 ubuntu192.168.110.130 packetbeat[61101]: Exiting: error connecting to Kibana: fail to get the Kibana version: HTTP GET request to http://localhost:5601/api/status fails: fail to execute the HTTP GET req>
Mar 02 02:40:44 ubuntu192.168.110.130 systemd[1]: packetbeat.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 681.`
chech config packetbeat.yaml file on ubuntu
